# How to structure a Typescript Interface for this Firebase Response JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, typescript, firebase, angular

I have this JSON response returning from Firebase

```
{ "-KD8Evk7TULU6t6zxMHl": { "createdAt": 1458296568840, "isActive": true, "title": "...add a title", "updatedAt": 1458296568840 } }
```

**Part 1 of Question**: How should I structure my Typescript Interface for the above JSON? For example, like the below?

```
export interface Hero {
  [id: string]: {
    createdAt: number;
    isActive: boolean;
    title: string;
    updatedAt: number;
  }
}
```

**Part 2 of Question**: How should I get the title or id of a hero using the recommended Typescript interface structure? For example I want to display the hero id and hero title

```
<html>
  ...omitted code for simplicity. I want to display hero id and title below.
  <h1> {{ hero.id }} </h1>
  <h1> {{ hero.title }} </h1>
</html>
```

Comment: Please split into two separate questions. That will also allow one that be purely about Angular2 and the other just about Typescript.

Comment: I'll do it better the next time. Thanks for your reminder

Answer (score 1):

1. Part 1

You can use this way or build a class which has another property "keyId" which will store the ID received from the firebase response object ("-KD8Evk7TULU6t6zxMHl"). In the constructor you should fill the keyId prop with id received. It is a bit more complicated though and will need to make a new class for each json line.

2. Part 2

If you stick with your option 1, then you must read from your object using the "Object" class--> hero[Object.keys(hero)[0]].title or just Object.keys(hero)[0] if you want the id.
It's a bit annoying but I can't see another way, unless you change your interface to a class with constructor like i mentioned before then you can go something like hero[hero.keyId].title, or hero.keyId for the id ;)